# Combining SQL Queries to pass result from 1 as a parameter of the 2nd (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a little out of practice with SQL and I am trying to verify some data that has been converted in a system. Some of the queries I originally developed prior to the conversion are not proving out the work. I have been able to trace the source data back and verify that conversion was correct, but this is on an account by account basis. I would like to have a query to show the full dataset.

I have been able to work a solution down to 2 queries, but I cannot figure out how to combine them into one piece to show the full data set, where one value from the first query needs to be an element in the second query.

Query 1

```
select distinct 
    CreatedDate, AccountNum 
From 
    Table1 A
Join 
    Table2 B on A.Column1 = B.Column1 and a.Column2 = b.Column2
Join 
    Table3 C on A.Column3 = C.Column3 and A.Column4 = C.Column4
where 
    Condition A and Condition B
```

Query 2

```
Select distinct 
    AccountNum, Responsible
From 
    Table3 D
Join 
    Table4 E on D.Column1 = E.Column2
where 
    StartDate <= 'DateValue' and EndDate > 'DateValue'
```

I would like to use the `CreatedDate` value from query 1 as the `DateValue` in query 2, but I have not found a solution to give the results I am looking for.

If I add a qualifier to each query, like account number, I end up with 1 result from query 1. I then put that `CreatedDate` into query 2 and I get the results I want.  If I only have the account number on the 2nd query, I get two results, one from time period A to B with a responsible value of X and the 2nd from time period C to D with Responsible Value Y, which is where the `CreateDate` value falls between.  Everything I have tried to combine these queries either ends up with a Responsible value of X (or no results), when I want that Y value.

I have not been able to successfully integrate the two queries, so that I can have that CreatedDate value passed as a parameter to figure out the Responsible value.

A solution that would work would be to create an intermediate table for the results of the 1st query and then join that table to 2nd query.  However, I do not have access to create/insert/update tables/records on the database, so I cannot use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
SELECT DISTINCT accountnum, 
                responsible 
FROM   table1 A 
       JOIN table2 B 
         ON A.column1 = B.column1 
            AND a.column2 = b.column2 
       JOIN table3 C 
         ON A.column3 = C.column3 
            AND A.column4 = C.column4 
       JOIN table4 D 
         ON D.column1 = C.column2 
            AND startdate <= createddate 
            AND enddate > createddate 
where  Condition A and Condition B
```

**Note:** You may have to add proper `alias` name to the `columns`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make the first query into a table-valued UDF:

```
Create function GetCreateDateAndAcctId([Parameters for 2 conditions here])
Returns table As
Return
   select distinct CreatedDate, AccountNum 
   From Table1 a
      Join Table2 b 
          on b.Column1 = a.Column1 
             and b.Column2 = a.Column2
      Join Table3 c 
          on c.Column3 = a.Column3 
             and c.Column4 = a.Column4
   where condition1   --  here put predicate    
       and condition2 -- using input parameters
```

Then, to use it, just include it as a table in your second query like this:

```
Select distinct AccountNum, Responsible
From Table3 d
    Join Table4 e
       on e.Column2 = d.Column1
    outer apply dbo.GetCreateDateAndAcctId(Parameters) cd
where StartDate <= cd.CreatedDate and EndDate > cd.CreatedDate
```

If you do this, the logic for the first query remains in a separate database object for reusability (you can use it in any other process without copying it). and better maintainability, (it's in only one place for fixing bugs and enhancements, etc. Also, since it's a table valued UDF, the SQL Server query processor will actually combine it with the second query's SQL into a single reusable compiled execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct AccountNum, Responsible
  From Table3 D
  Join Table4 E on D.Column1 = E.Column2
  Join (
        select distinct CreatedDate, AccountNum 
          From Table1 A
          Join Table2 B on A.Column1 = B.Column1 and a.Column2 = b.Column2
          Join Table3 C on A.Column3 = C.Column3 and A.Column4 = C.Column4
         where Condition A and Condition B
       ) X
    on D.AccountNum=X.AccountNum
   and D.StartDate <= X.CreatedDate and EndDate > X.CreatedDate
```